# Why I am not able to get some key-values from JSON object?

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api

**Scenario:**

I am working on the Slack custom app in Node.js where I need a list of users and send the "names" of the users a drop-down list in Slack dialog.

I am getting a list of users perfectly fine in a long JSON object having key name "members" of type array, then using `foreach` to iterate over "members" array and extracting users' names.

**Problem:**

In "members" array there is an object for every user having their "id", "name", "team_id", ""real_name"
 etc. 
When I am extracting "name" and sending it in response it's working fine and populating list in a Dialog but when I send "real_name" it stops working and in Dialog, I can't see any entry.

Please have a look at the following code:

```
        slack.users.list({
                token: userToken
            })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log("users", response.members);
                if(response.members.length !== 0){
                    console.log("Inside users if");
                    response.members.forEach((userObject) => {
                        //at this line I am getting userObject.real_name correct
                        var userName = {
                            "label" : userObject.real_name,
                            "value" : userObject.real_name
                        }
                        // at this line I checked, "userName" is creating fine
                        assignToList.push(userName);
                        //at this line I checked, "assignToList" is creating fine
                    });
                    res.send({options: assignToList});
                }

            })
            .catch(error => console.error("Error while getting users list", error));
```

JSON of users list:

```
users { ok: true, members: [ { id: 'USLACKBOT', team_id: 'T894JCLMV', name: 'slackbot', deleted: false, color: '757575', real_name: 'Slackbot', tz: null, tz_label: 'Pacific Daylight Time', tz_offset: -25200, profile: [Object], is_admin: false, is_owner: false, is_primary_owner: false, is_restricted: false, is_ultra_restricted: false, is_bot: false, is_app_user: false, updated: 0 }, { id: 'U87GKAELR', team_id: 'T894JCLMV', name: 'hamza.tariq.it', deleted: false, color: '9f69e7', real_name: 'Hamza', tz: 'Australia/Canberra', tz_label: 'Australian Eastern Standard Time', tz_offset: 36000, profile: [Object], is_admin: true, is_owner: true, is_primary_owner: false, is_restricted: false, is_ultra_restricted: false, is_bot: false, is_app_user: false, updated: 1569099496, has_2fa: false }, { id: 'U8855S4CS', team_id: 'T894JCLMV', name: 'ybot', deleted: false, color: 'e7392d', real_name: 'Hybris Commerce Bot', tz: 'America/Los_Angeles', tz_label: 'Pacific Daylight Time', tz_offset: -25200, profile: [Object], is_admin: false, is_owner: false, is_primary_owner: false, is_restricted: false, is_ultra_restricted: false, is_bot: true, is_app_user: false, updated: 1530835779 }, { id: 'U8976PQCF', team_id: 'T894JCLMV', name: 'hybrisbot', deleted: false, color: '4bbe2e', real_name: 'yIntegration', tz: 'America/Los_Angeles', tz_label: 'Pacific Daylight Time', tz_offset: -25200, profile: [Object], is_admin: false, is_owner: false, is_primary_owner: false, is_restricted: false, is_ultra_restricted: false, is_bot: true, is_app_user: false, updated: 1569099496 }, { id: 'UCQ1WRY4S', team_id: 'T894JCLMV', name: 'mahwishhamza97', deleted: false, color: '3c989f', real_name: 'Brian Lara', tz: 'Australia/Canberra', tz_label: 'Australian Eastern Standard Time', tz_offset: 36000, profile: [Object], is_admin: false, is_owner: false, is_primary_owner: false, is_restricted: false, is_ultra_restricted: false, is_bot: false, is_app_user: false, updated: 1569099496, has_2fa: false }, { id: 'UCR58NWMD', team_id: 'T894JCLMV', name: 'prioritybot', deleted: false, color: '674b1b', real_name: 'prioritybot', tz: 'America/Los_Angeles', tz_label: 'Pacific Daylight Time', tz_offset: -25200, profile: [Object], is_admin: false, is_owner: false, is_primary_owner: false, is_restricted: false, is_ultra_restricted: false, is_bot: true, is_app_user: false, updated: 1548659099 }, { id: 'UCR5YEXUZ', team_id: 'T894JCLMV', name: 'siddarth.pugazhendi', deleted: false, color: 'e0a729', real_name: 'Siddarth Pugazhendi', tz: 'Australia/Canberra', tz_label: 'Australian Eastern Standard Time', tz_offset: 36000, profile: [Object], is_admin: false, is_owner: false, is_primary_owner: false, is_restricted: false, is_ultra_restricted: false, is_bot: false, is_app_user: false, updated: 1569099496, has_2fa: false }, { id: 'UCRGZU0SG', team_id: 'T894JCLMV', name: 'pasquale.campitiello', deleted: false, color: '2b6836', real_name: 'Pasquale', tz: 'Australia/Canberra', tz_label: 'Australian Eastern Standard Time', tz_offset: 36000, profile: [Object], is_admin: false, is_owner: false, is_primary_owner: false, is_restricted: false, is_ultra_restricted: false, is_bot: false, is_app_user: false, updated: 1569099496, has_2fa: false }, { id: 'UCRNZKTSN', team_id: 'T894JCLMV', name: 'usman.kamal', deleted: false, color: '5b89d5', real_name: 'Usman Kamal', tz: 'Asia/Karachi', tz_label: 'Pakistan Standard Time', tz_offset: 18000, profile: [Object], is_admin: true, is_owner: false, is_primary_owner: false, is_restricted: false, is_ultra_restricted: false, is_bot: false, is_app_user: false, updated: 1569099496, has_2fa: false }, { id: 'UCRTWG79B', team_id: 'T894JCLMV', name: 'felipe.rodrigues', deleted: false, color: '99a949', real_name: 'Felipe', tz: 'Australia/Canberra', tz_label: 'Australian Eastern Stan
```

Comment: What error message do you get? Where do you get an error?

Comment: There is no error message occurring. I am deploying it on google cloud functions but it in logs there is no error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got resolved.

**Problem:**

In "members" array there were some `undefined` values for "real_name" field as well which were creating this issue.

**Solution:**

Just added an `if` check to validate if "real_name" is valid. It worked like a charm.

```
if(response.members.length !== 0){
            response.members.forEach((userObject) => {
                if(userObject.real_name){ //added this check
                var userName = {
                    "label" : userObject.real_name,
                    "value" : userObject.id
                }
                assignToList.push(userName);
                }
            });
            res.send({options: assignToList});
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

change your response to:

`response.members.members.forEach`

From: `response.members.forEach`

I will suggest you to look at API documentation carefully though..

Comment: Why is that so? An object is pretty straight forward there is not "members" field in "members".

Comment: When you console logged response.members, it is an object with "ok": string and "members": Member[]

Comment: console.log("users", response.members);
users { ok: true, members: [ { id: 'USLACKBOT ....